# How can I visualize the Mastermorphix 3x3 modification?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

I bought a Mastermorphix a while ago and I’m just starting to want to figure out how to solve it, which is great because it came with instructions. The instructions are telling me that the mastermorphix is a 3x3 Rubik’s cube, and that I should solve it just like a 3x3. But I can’t imagine the 3x3 Rubik’s cube and the Mastermorphix being the same thin I’m trying to imagine how, if I edited the masterphix model in a model editor, I could make it look just like a 3x3. But I just can’t seem to find a website that explains how they are the same thing, much less show a mastermorphix right next to a 3x3, and then explain what would be what on the 3x3 to the mastermorphix.

How can I visualize the Mastermorphix 3x3 modification?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The best way to familiarize yourself is to play with the puzzle physically and observe what appears to be centers (not moving), edges, and corners.

Answer (score 1):

Having trouble visualizing the faces of your Mastermorphix?
Consider repainting them to see what they really look like:

> [image]
>  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? It doesn't have a regular cube side-by-side, but does identify the corresponding pieces.
[image]

(copied from https://rubiks.fandom.com/wiki/Mastermorphix)

I don't own a Mastermorphix, but it looks there is at least one minor difference. With a regular cube, you don't care about centre orientation unless you have one with pictures or other patterns on the faces. The equivalent pieces on the Mastermorphix have two colours, so orientation matters. I don't know how much that will affect solutions.

The edges of a cube are equivalent to the single-colour quadrilateral pieces on the Mastermorphix. Orientation of those pieces affects the shape of the Mastermorphix instead of swapping colours as it would on a cube.

Comment: I don’t know how big a difference it really makes, but the one i have is more round, instead of plain pyramid.

Comment: Also, the instructions it came with explained all that. What im having problems with is seeing it as a 3x3. If i can make that connection then i can solve it no problem, but for now i see it as a piece of art with pieces sticking out all over the place

Comment: If yours is different, perhaps provide a picture of yours.